# Wacom button and mouse button setting

Tags: software-installation, settings, wacom, button

I use my Wacom Intuos Pro. And it works very well. I try to use the pad buttons work like the left and right mouse buttons. But I can not. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a different tablet, but I use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
#
# the darn thing change names if is on wireless or not...
#
device=$(xsetwacom --list | grep -i "pad" |  awk '{print $(NF-2)}')

xsetwacom --set "$device" button 1 "key ctrl z"
xsetwacom --set "$device" button 3 "key shift ctrl s"
xsetwacom --set "$device" button 8 "key shift ctrl l"
echo "Ok --- all set on device $device."

exit 0
```

It will need a bit of try and error to find the buttons; what I do is normally use a script assigning a letter to each key an clicking in a terminal to check, like

```
xsetwacom --set "$device" button 1 "key 1"
xsetwacom --set "$device" button 2 "key 2"
```

... and so on.

The manual of `xsetwacom` says:

> ```
>  Button button-number [mapping]
>           Set a mapping for the specified button-number. Mappings take the
>           form of either a single numeric button or an 'action' to be per‐
>           formed. If no  mapping  is  provided,  the  default  mapping  is
>           restored.
>
>           Numeric  button  mappings  indicate  what  X11 button number the
>           given button-number should correspond to. For example, a mapping
>           of  "3" means a press of the given button-number will produce as
>           a press of X11 button 3 (i.e. right click).
> ```

so to define the buttons 1 and 2 (example out of the blue) to left and right mouse button you should do:

```
xsetwacom --set "$device" button 1 1
xsetwacom --set "$device" button 2 3
```

(not tested, I have my tablet at the office).

Comment: I now have a comparative problem https://askubuntu.com/q/1063216/501719